# When i perform poptorootview controller the first view controllers textfield being blank

Tags: ios, iphone

When i perform poptorootview controller the first view controllers textfield should be blank

so i have to create that some value that not be blank like username textfield must be shown saved username

Comment: Use NSUserDefaults to save data.

Comment: it really works for me.